# gcc is not working on snow leopard

Tags: gcc, osx-snow-leopard

After upgrading to snow leopard it turn out that i am unable to use gcc on terminal anymore, and its mainly because it has lose its link in /usr/bin/.

What should i do to make it work again?

[After installing Xcode 3.2, everything went to normal, terminal was accepting gcc command, but i have to shutdown once, because netbeans was not working properly, so after shutdown, its looking great]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reinstall XCode from the Snow Leopard installation media, and when asking what to install, make sure you select command-line tools.

Comment: I am download xcode 3.2 with iphone sdk 3.1, because i have noticed that its no within snow leopard installation media (iphone sdk). Will update on this once i install that new version.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to install XCode 3.2 supplied on the Snow Leopard DVD